# Pandas filter dataframe off sliced value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
names        brand
A7           Audi
TrailBlazer  Chevy
RS8          Audi
Tahoe        Chevy
Corvette     Chevy
GL450        Mercedes
```

I would like to filter the df off of a slice of the names column. I want to use the last character of the value. If the the last character is a digit I want to 'ignore' that and return only the other results.

I am trying this.

```
new_df = df[(df['names'] == (lambda x: x['names'].str[-1]).isdigit())]
```

When I do this it returns a empty dataframe.

I would expect to return this.

```
names       brand
TrailBlazer Chevy
Tahoe       Chevy
Corvette    Chevy
```

Comment: What's your expected output for the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str[-1]` to access the last character of the strings, and use `str.isdigit()` to test the condition:

```
df[~df.names.str[-1].str.isdigit()]
#         names   brand
#1  TrailBlazer   Chevy
#3        Tahoe   Chevy
#4     Corvette   Chevy
```

Or more safely, in case you have numeric values in the *names* column:

```
df[~df.names.astype(str).str[-1].str.isdigit()]
```